# Bulkify the trigger and how to avoid two loop

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger OpcrrtunityTrigger on Opcrrtunity (after insert) {
    Map<Id,Opcrrtunity> OpcrrtunityMap = new Map<Id,Opcrrtunity>();
    List<Child_Record__c> crlist = new List<Child_Record__c>();
    for(Opcrrtunity opp : trigger.new){
        if(opp.Contract_Term__c!=NULL && opp.Implementation_Date__c != NULL )
        OpcrrtunityMap.put(opp.Id,opp);
    }
    If(OpcrrtunityMap.size()>0){
        for(Opcrrtunity o : OpcrrtunityMap.values()){
            for(Integer i=0; i<o.Contract_Term__c; i++){
                Child_Record__c cr = new Child_Record__c();
                    cr.Opcrrtunity_Name__c = o.Name; 
                    cr.Amount__c = o.Amount;
                    cr.Closed_Date__c = o.CloseDate;
                    cr.Month_No__c = o.Month_No__c;
                    cr.Stage__c = o.StageName;
                    cr.Probability__c = o.Probability;
                    cr.Projected_Implementation_Date__c = o.Implementation_Date__c.addMonths(i);
                    cr.Contract_Term__c=o.Contract_Term__c;
                    cr.Monthly_Projected_Revenue__c = o.Projected_Revenue_1__c;
                    cr.Target_Revenue__c = o.Q1RF_target__c;
                    cr.Opcrrtunity__c = o.Id; 
                    crlist.add(cr);
            }
            insert crlist;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You just need to move the `insert crlist` outside the loop. If you need one record per month, with processing bulk number of records in a trigger, a loop-in-a-loop is about the best you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using loop inside loop by using

```
    List<Contract_Term__c> newContract = new List<Contract_Term__c>();
    for(Opcrrtunity o : OpcrrtunityMap.values()){ 
         newContract.add(o.Contract_Term__c);
     }
    for(Contract_Term__c c : newContract){
          Child_Record__c cr = new Child_Record__c();
                    cr.Opcrrtunity_Name__c = o.Name; 
                    cr.Amount__c = o.Amount;
                    cr.Closed_Date__c = o.CloseDate;
                    cr.Month_No__c = o.Month_No__c;
                    cr.Stage__c = o.StageName;
                    cr.Probability__c = o.Probability;
                    cr.Projected_Implementation_Date__c = o.Implementation_Date__c.addMonths(i);
                    cr.Contract_Term__c=o.Contract_Term__c;
                    cr.Monthly_Projected_Revenue__c = o.Projected_Revenue_1__c;
                    cr.Target_Revenue__c = o.Q1RF_target__c;
                    cr.Opcrrtunity__c = o.Id; 
                    crlist.add(cr);
    }
insert crlist;
```

Comment: how to create multiple record by this method... Logic is based on Contract_Term__c field, if the field value is 10 then it will create 10 child record

Answer (score 0):

First, be careful with DML statements like `insert` inside for loops. This is a bad practice. There are some limits allowed by Salesforce on the number of DML statements allowed in a single transaction.

So your `insert crlist` statement should be called outside the for loops. At the end.

Then, you can avoid the two loops through your opportunities record. Your `map` declaration is useless.

Here's the right code:

```
trigger OpcrrtunityTrigger on Opcrrtunity (after insert) {
    List<Child_Record__c> crlist = new List<Child_Record__c>();
    for(Opcrrtunity opp : trigger.new){
        if(opp.Contract_Term__c!=NULL && opp.Implementation_Date__c != NULL){
            for(Integer i=0; i<opp.Contract_Term__c; i++){
                Child_Record__c cr = new Child_Record__c();
                    cr.Opcrrtunity_Name__c = opp.Name; 
                    cr.Amount__c = opp.Amount;
                    cr.Closed_Date__c = opp.CloseDate;
                    cr.Month_No__c = opp.Month_No__c;
                    cr.Stage__c = opp.StageName;
                    cr.Probability__c = opp.Probability;
                    cr.Projected_Implementation_Date__c = opp.Implementation_Date__c.addMonths(i);
                    cr.Contract_Term__c=opp.Contract_Term__c;
                    cr.Monthly_Projected_Revenue__c = opp.Projected_Revenue_1__c;
                    cr.Target_Revenue__c = opp.Q1RF_target__c;
                    cr.Opcrrtunity__c = opp.Id; 
                    crlist.add(cr);
            }
        }
    }
    insert crlist;
}
```

Comment: I tried with this but got the same error

Comment: What same error? You didn't mention any error first.

Comment: System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 151

Comment: Are you sure you used my code?

Comment: Yes!  Martin Lezer

Comment: Do you have a trigger linked to your Child_Record__c object?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a questionable design if `o.Contract_Term__c` can be a large number. You mention 10 in your comment to another answer, but if that number can be say 1,000 you will run into governor limits pretty easily.

It would make more sense to insert one `Child_Record__c` (as Saumya has it) and then reference the `Contract_Term__c` via the relationship field to the `Opportunity` (or `Opcrrtunity` as you have it). Or if you can guarantee that value never changes you could copy the value into `Child_Record__c` if that was more convenient.

Comment: Thanks! Keith, value will always change into Contract_Term__c field, as per the value it will create child records. For example if value = 2 then it should create 2 new records or if value equal 6 then It should be create 6 new record

Comment: @Maggie I'm suggesting that creating a record for each of these is perhaps not the best design choice. Reasons include governor limit restrictions and cost (as each row consumes 2k and storage is expensive). Why do you need a record for each?

Comment: @ Keith, Actually there is some requirement where I need to create child record based on Parent Object Number field.

So, I bit confused how to avoid inside for loop.

Comment: @Maggie As others have said, you can move the insert to the end of the trigger outside of the loop. If I was implementing this, I'd go back to whoever wrote the requirement to create many objects and check that they understand the implications.